# window.extAsyncInit() not being called from Messenger Extensions JS SDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

In the "Adding Messenger Extensions" guide posted below, **window.extAsyncInit() is NOT FIRING after the Messenger Extensions JS SDK is done loading**

1) domain is whitelisted
2) I am performing res.sendFile with a bare bones html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
    (function(d, s, id){
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.com/en_US/messenger.Extensions.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'Messenger'));

    window.extAsyncInit = function() {
    // the Messenger Extensions JS SDK is done loading 
    alert("This alert isnt being executed in webview or chrome 
    mobile");

    MessengerExtensions.getUserID(function success(uids) {
    // User ID was successfully obtained. 
    var psid = uids.psid;
    }, function error(err, errorMessage) {      
    // Error handling code
    });   
   };
   </script>
   <h1>
   Basic Text
   </h1>
 </body>
</html>'
```

3) I am accessing via persistent menu button with messenger_extensions parameter is set to true.

**4) The weird behavior I am seeing with my iphone 6:**

A. In webview, the alert never comes up

B. On mobile browser, the alert comes up in Safari but not Chrome

C. If I press "Request Desktop Site" while in Chrome mobile , the alert pops up

D. On my Mac (Sierra), the alert pops up in Safari and Chrome

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/extensions

Comment: hey man! i'm in the same situation! have u found a solution?